# Java File and Files classes both not recognizing UNC directories

Tags: java

I've created both a File and Files object in Java based on a UNC path.  When I check to see if the object isDirectory, both classes return false:

```
        sourceDirectory = new File( "\\\\mymachine\\test\\new\\" );
        boolean b = sourceDirectory.isDirectory();
        Path path = sourceDirectory.toPath();
        boolean a = Files.isDirectory( path );

        results:  b=false and a=false
```

What do I need to do to have my UNC directory recognized as a directory by File and Files?

Comment: Are you working in a domain or work group environment? In a domain environment Win7 & Sun Java 7 your code works fine.

Comment: Ultimately, in a workgroup.  In my test above, however, the code is actually pointing to the same machine it is running on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are doing that correctly, but your local test case is misleading you.
For a windows path on a network share, your code would work fine, but for a local
path on your computer, you still need to specify the drive letter:

```
    File netDir = new File("\\\\usstll0032\\share\\drc"); // network drive
    System.out.println(netDir.isDirectory()); // true

    File badDir = new File("\\\\us39-0cmq142\\temp"); // my computer
    System.out.println(badDir.isDirectory());  // false

    File goodDir = new File("\\\\us39-0cmq142\\c$\\temp"); // my computer
    System.out.println(goodDir.isDirectory()); // true
```